# Using k-nearest neighbour without splitting into training and test sets

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I have the following dataset, with over 20,000 rows:

[image]

I want to use columns A through E to predict column X using a k-nearest neighbor algorithm. I have tried to use `KNeighborsRegressor` from sklearn, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from numpy.random import permutation
import math
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

random_indices = permutation(df.index)
test_cutoff = int(math.floor(len(df)/5))
test = df.loc[random_indices[1:test_cutoff]]
train = df.loc[random_indices[test_cutoff:]]

x_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', D', E']
y_column = ['X']

knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=100, weights='distance')
knn.fit(train[x_columns], train[y_column])
predictions = knn.predict(test[x_columns])
```

This only makes predictions on the test data which is a fifth of the original dataset. I also want prediction values for the training data.

To do this, I tried to implement my own k-nearest algorithm by calculating the Euclidean distance for each row from every other row, finding the k shortest distances, and averaging the X value from those k rows.  This process took over 30 seconds for just one row, and I have over 20,000 rows.  Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: So you fit the `KNeighorsRegressor` on the training data and predicted onto test. You've already got a trained model, so why not just do `knn.predict(train[x_columns])`? Or maybe you ought to do *k*-fold cross-validation so no rows are ever left out of "test." You basically would build an averaged model from CV and predict on everything. Or just fit a model on the whole dataset and predict over the whole dataset: `knn.fit(df[x_columns], df[y_column])`.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, but it just predicts exactly the value of the X column.  Modelling over the whole dataset does the same.  As I mentioned at the end of my question, I basically implemented k-fold cross-validation but it just takes so long for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
X = np.asarray(df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']])
y = np.asarray(df['X'])

rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=1./5, random_state=0)
train_indices, test_indices = rs.split(X).next()

knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=100, weights='distance')
knn.fit(X[train_indices], y[train_indices])

predictions = knn.predict(X)
```

The main difference with respect to your solution is the use of [`ShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html).

Notes:

- `predictions` contains the predicted values for all your data (test and train).
- The proportion of test data can be adjusted through the parameter `test_size` (I used your setting, i.e. one fifth).
- It is necessary to call the method `next()` for the iterator to yield the indices of the train and test data.

Answer (score 1):

> To do this, I tried to implement my own k-nearest algorithm by calculating the Euclidean distance for each row from every other row, finding the k shortest distances, and averaging the X value from those k rows. This process took over 30 seconds for just one row, and I have over 20,000 rows. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Yes, the problem is that loops in python are extremely slow. What you can do is **vectorize** your computations. So lets say that your data is in matrix X  (n x d), then matrix of distances D_ij = || X_i - X_j ||^2 is

```
D = X^2 + X'^2 -  2 X X'
```

so in Python

```
D = (X ** 2).sum(1).reshape(-1, 1) + (X ** 2).sum(1).reshape(1, -1) - 2*X.dot(X.T)
```

Comment: So would the distances for each the row of data be the rows or columns of matrix D?

Comment: D_ij element will be a squared distance between X_i and X_j. Since distance matrix is symmetric, you can interpret both row- or columnwise (but mathematically - i'th row represents distances of X_i from all remaining ones).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split the data into train and test if you want predictions on training data only.

You can just fit the original data then make predictions on it.

```
model.fit(original data, target)
model.predict(original data)
```